# What is this operator:content value mean?

Tags: views

What is this operator:content mean?

1) Under Content:Title

[image]

2) Click on Content:Title, under Configure filter criterion: Content: Title, there is a operator:content. What does value mean?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator shown in the screenshot is *Contains*. Since that is a filter for *Content: title*, it will show nodes whose titles contain the string you put in the *Value* field.

To make a summary, that view will show nodes, where:

- The node is published
- The content type is *Webform*
- The node title contains *style 2*

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, you can think of `Content` as being "node". So the title of the node.

Since you have `Content Type (=webform)` as a filter, then `Content: Title` would be the Title of your web form.

Where this could change, is if you add a relationship, EX: Terms of the node, and then select a relationship for your title field. Then it would be the title of a taxonomy term, or some other thing/entity. Depends on the relationship you add.